# kubuntu - vlc or smplayer video quality settings for HD movies (mkv etc...)

Tags: kubuntu, video-player, mplayer, smplayer

I have ubuntu 12.04.02 with kde 4.10 with 3d effects. 
I have a recent very fast PC. I have a ATI msi R6870 video card fglrx proprietary drivers 13.1.
I have used video tearing option to reduce video tearing.

I would like to know the best quality video settings for **vlc** or **smplayer** for **HD** mkv videos.
In particular I have seen these settings:

- video output/output driver
- accelerated video output (overlay)
- deinterlacing and deinterlacing type
- gpu accelerated decoding and other codecs options
- filters (i think sharpen is good maybe)
- and other Advanced Video settings

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- video output/output driver: OpenGL GLX video output (XCB)
- Accelerated video output (Overlay): On
- Deinterlacing: On
- Deinterlacing: Yadif (x2)

  > Note: If Yadif (x2) too powerful and lags, use Bob instead, perhaps with 'Automatic' setting]
- Use GPU accelerated decoding: Yes
- Video quality post-processing level: 6

If lag persists; Skip H.264 in-loop deblocking filter: All

- x264 preset and tuning selection: ultrafast and zero latency

Additional:

- Tools -> Preferences -> 'Advanced'/'All' settings -> Input / Codecs -> Video Codecs -> x264 -> Integer pixel motion estimation method

  - Default is hex, use umh for higher quality.
- Value below 'hex' or 'umh' is Maximum motion vector search range. Default: 16

  - Set anywhere between 16-64.
  - Personally, I've found that hex set at 64 outdoes umh set at 32, and creates less lag.